# Syntax error when evaluating variable assignment statements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, eval, jupyter-lab

I'm running one jupyter notebook from another using the %run magic

I want to pass parameters to the called notebook in the form

%run notebook.ipynb param1=value1 param2=value2 ...

Therefore I've created the following code:

```
#sys.argv
p = ['data_csv=data2.csv','master=lala','data_dir=./data']
parameters = list(
    map(lambda s: re.sub('$', '"', s),
        map(lambda s: s.replace('=','="'),
            filter(
                lambda s: s.find('=') > -1,
                p
            )
        )
    )
)

for parameter in parameters:
    eval(parameter)
```

Unfortunately I get

```
     data_csv="data2.csv"
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: From the [%run doc](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run), "parameters after the filename are passed as command-line arguments to the program (put in sys.argv)". Can't you just drop the `paramX=` element before the `valueX`?

Comment: `eval()` can be used on expression only, no assignments. But you can put the assignment before the `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

As Klaus D. commented, *eval* can't be used for assignments, but *exec* can, therefore the working solution looks like this:

```
import sys
import re
p = ['data_csv=data2.csv','master=lala','data_dir=./data']
parameters = list(
    map(lambda s: re.sub('$', '"', s),
        map(lambda s: s.replace('=','="'),
            filter(
                lambda s: s.find('=') > -1,
                p
            )
        )
    )
)

for parameter in parameters:
    exec(parameter)
```